# Jquery afer ajax call ok but ID is not sent?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with JQuery and making a ajax call to delete some stuff form database based on ID like this:

```
$(".delete").live('click', function(event) {
                  var item = $(this),
                      commentContainer = item.parent(),
                      id = item.attr("id"),
                      string = 'solutionID=' + id;
                      item.next('.loading2').fadeIn();

                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/js/ajax/delete-comment.php",
                    data: string,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(){
                      commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {
                        item.remove();
                        $('.loading2').fadeOut();
                      });
                    }
                  });
                  event.preventDefault();
                });
```

The page itself has this:-

```
<a href="#" id="55" class="delete">DELETE</a><div class="loading2"></div>
```

It works the first time and I am using "live()" to make sure that it works after the ajax call too. 
Nevertheless after the ajax call it seems to work but the ID of the element is not posted, although is there.

Anyone has an idea about this problem? Please

THANK YOU AVERYBODY. I FOUND THE PROBLEM:

It wasn't Jquery or html related but a missed call in SQL query for solution.solutionID.
My apologies.

Comment: Can you check in console if there is any error

Comment: No error at all. Just the ID=

Comment: I think we need more code after all =/

Comment: Are you sure you get the ID? try to print it with console.log(id);

Comment: The ID is there (code above). It just not posted but it does it before the ajax call.

Comment: You should use `this.id` not `$(this).attr('id')`. If you write `alert(this.id);` what does the alert-box return? I assume the ID is missing? In that case, the problem is not the javascript, it's your html-markup.

Comment: I think is html problem but the markup seems ok (see above). the problem is why it does work ok first time but not after ajax call?

Comment: PS alert(this.id) return empty

Comment: Your AJAX call doesn't add any elements to the DOM, so it's not a problem with the event handler binding using `live()`. Can you post more of the HTML markup (more than one of the delete links)?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that prior to HTML5 it's not valid to have IDs that begin with a digit.

Comment: Anthony, I don't see the reason for posting unrelated code. It's all there. Besides if there was a problem in the html page it wouldn't work the first time but it does. it just doesn't after first call. I will go through the html code anyway and see if all looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".delete").on('click', function(e) {
    var item = $(this);
    var commentContainer = item.parent();
    str = 'solutionID=' + this.id;
    item.next('.loading2').fadeIn();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/js/ajax/delete-comment.php",
        data: str,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {
                item.remove();
                $('.loading2').fadeOut();
            });
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank yo ubut still ID is empty

Comment: Updated answer, really weird. You are using Firebug or something to see what data is sent?

Comment: Woops, did something wrong when posting. Try one more time. If it does not work, you should update your question with a jsfiddle.net example.

Comment: You just changed Live() with 0n()?

Comment: You should not use live anymore. Does the event actually fire? If you write (as I said) `alert(this.id);` in the beginning of the function, what does the box say?

Comment: Thank yuo Optimus found the problm (above). What shall I use insted of live then? If I dont' use it after the ajax call Jquery does not work

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are using to pass in the id is called `string`, isn't that a data type in javascript? Try renaming it to something else. It might be un-related, but it kinda smells a bit odd.

Comment: Ah, beaten in a second. I think there's something else wrong with this tho (as he gets half of the string's content sent).